# Node.js Fetch Request Hangs on await response.text()

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

I am using the new Fetch API in Node 20 to make a GET request.

The response body is XML.

While a response is received almost immediately, awaiting response.text() can hang or timeout  if the response body is large (e.g. over 900 KB)

```
 try {

    const headers = {
    "Content-Type": 'text/xml'    
    }

    const req_options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: headers
    };    

    const fetch_response = await fetch(req_url, req_options);
    console.log("fetch_response: " + fetch_response && fetch_response.status) // <= returns 200 almost immediately

    let text

    if (fetch_response && fetch_response.status >= 200 && fetch_response.status < 300) {
      text = await fetch_response.text()
      console.log(text) // <= hangs or times out if response body is > 900 KB
      return text
    } else {
      console.log("Request error")
      return "" // <= this does not trigger - i.e. response status is ok
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return { success: false, error: error }
  }
```

Have I correctly diagnosed this as a size issue (all requests returning a smaller response seem to work)?

Is there another way to convert these large responses to XML text using the Fetch API in Node?

Comment: _`fetch_response >= 200`_ huh?

Comment: FYI you can use the [Response: ok property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) instead of checking status codes

Comment: What sort of values are in `headers`? 900kb is by no means _large_ and shouldn't cause any issues

Comment: updated typo fetch_response.status >= 200

Comment: added headers "Content-Type": 'text/xml'

Comment: GET requests do not require a content-type header

Comment: header is not the problem, however

Comment: Never said it was. Unfortunately this is not reproducible. I can fetch megabytes of data without issue. This question requires a lot more information about your environment and possibly the environment of the service providing the data